# How to get double widehats to be aligned well

Tags: symbols

I tried to use `$\widehat{[\widehat{Q}^*]}$`, but the things inside the square bracket are aligned ugly, so what I intended was not obtained. Below, I attach my drawing for clarification. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be helpful if you clarified what is the intended result. Maybe you could add a sketch?

Comment: @Vincent, Thank you for the suggestion. I added an image.

Comment: @metric: When I compile [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/QVd4iak5) minimal example I obtain [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BCwt.png) output, which seem to match what you expect. Can you provide a minimal example that replicates your unexpected behaviour?

Comment: @Werner, inspired by your comment, I deleted \usepackage{mathabx} in my tex file, so the same output as yours has been obtained. Thank you. By the way, I remember  \usepackage{mathabx} was added long time ago for some command to work properly, thus deleting it may cause something not to work well again. So, I'll check. (Also, I liked the archaic font made by \usepackage{mathabx}., so deleting it is a pity.) Anyway, thank you!

Comment: I obtain the expected result also by adding `\usepackage{mathabx}` to Werner's code. You have something else in your code which is messing up. Alas, without seeing the code it's anybody's guess...